# Android system recreating a killed activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

I have an activity that requires a parcelable object to be passed to it in the starting intent, I started getting few exception logs about null pointer exception caused by the fact that the intent that started the activity does not contain the bundle extra that contains the parcelable object.

So I started logging more data about the intent that started my activity and caused the exception along with other data in the `onCreate`and here is what I got

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference :
IsRoot : false 
Intent : Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10400000 cmp=MyBundle/MyActivity } Action : android.intent.action.MAIN
```

So I figured out that the activity is recreated by the system after being killed also by the system but the system does not pass the parcelable and the fact that I am logging from `onCreate` it means that `onNewIntent` will not be called, I tried to reproduce the exception by setting the **Do not keep the activities** option in the Developer options and when the activity is recreated it does not crash and by checking the log I found out that in that case the system passes the parcelable object when recreating the activity. and before any one mentions it I did not declare my activity to be Launcher activity in my Manifest.

I know I could just navigate away to the Launcher activity when this happens but could the system be passing the bundle that contains the parcelable object in away that I am missing?

Comment: Check if it is null, `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); if (b != null) {` in `onCreate`

Comment: @MehranZamani I know I could do that and in the case of the bundle is null I could launch the home activity but that is not a good user experience and also it's a work around to the problem.